# C#: weird ref in constructor to behave like "virtual field"

Tags: c#, nhibernate, constructor, ref

The background is that in NHibernate mapping, as the collection field is declared in base class and dynamically proxied at runtime.

As there is some proxy class which need refer to the collection field during my coding, however, as NHiberate reassign the field with its own collection instance, the proxy loses the reference.

Tried use `ref` to "track" the reference, but failed with weired outcome.

Can some experter help explain about the root cause with both C# ref keyword and NHiberate collection proxy if any.

Thanks.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var v = new D();
    }
}

class A
{
}

class B : A
{
}

class C
{
    public A a = new A();
    public Proxy p;

    public C()
    {
        p = new Proxy(ref a);
        p.Out();
    }
}

class D : C
{
    public D()
    {
        a = new B();
        Console.WriteLine(a.GetType().Name);
        p.Out();
    }
}


class Proxy
{
    public A a;

    public Proxy(ref A a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void Out()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a.GetType().Name);
    }
}
```

```
Expected output:
A
B
B

Actual output:
A
B
A
```

Answer (score 5):

> Tried use ref to "track" the reference, but failed with weired outcome.

There's nothing weird about this outcome - you just don't understand `ref` sufficiently. `ref` only affects the parameter it's declared on.

So on this line:

```
this.a = a;
```

you're *just* copying the current value of the `a` parameter into the `a` field. Any later changes to the value of the parameter within the constructor (not that there are any) will *not* be reflected in the field - and any changes to the variable which was used as the argument again won't be reflected in the field.

So changing the `a` field within the `C` class (it would really have helped if you'd used different names for the fields and parameters) doesn't change the value within the `Proxy` instance's `a` field at all.

Note that this has nothing to do with NHibernate, either - it's just the standard C# behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. Supposing I have a field in a base class and I know some subclass will reassign it, how can I track that reassignment so that base and subclass can ensure always referring to  the same object?